# Generate JWT on Firebase-side

Tags: ios, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication, layerkit

My application using Google's Firebase as backend, I'm happy with Firebase e-mail authentication and I have some users in database on it.

Currently I need to integrate [Layer (chat service)](https://docs.layer.com/sdk/ios/authentication) to my application, it uses JWT authentication tokens sign-in system, I want to make SSO with one e-mail/password to Firebase & Layer. Firebase supports JWT-authentication too, but I don't want to migrate all users from good e-mail authentication to custom JWT auth because:

- I don't want to buy new second server to make authentication there (so I will have: Auth Server, Firebase, Layer)
- I have already database with users, it will be a big headache to migrate them to 3rd-party authentication server
- 3rd party servers can't be trusted enough as Google's servers
- It will add a lot of code to support that

Is it any way to use Firebase email authorization and ask Firebase to generate JWT tokens (based on my data/nonce)?

Maybe there are some services that can help me to do that without loosing users database and headache?